# How many times can a simple user add a computer to windows domain?

Tags: permissions, active-directory

In a course about Windows Server administration that I took at the university they told us that a normal user could add 10 computers to a domain. Over the years however I've added and removed way more than 10 computers (virtual machines included) to the domain without any problems, while some colleagues of mine swear that they can't add any computers. My account is not priviledged in any aspect, I'm just a regular user like everyone else.

So... what are the rules governing this? Can they be changed by the admin? Is there any way I can find out with my user-level-priviledges?

Just curious. :)

Answer (score 6):

By default, any authenticated user can add up to 10 new computers to the domain.

This is controlled by the "Add workstations to domain" right, which can be found in the security policy under "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\".

Typically, this would be changed by the sysadmin when the domain is created in order to restrict this right to a specific group, usually "DOMAIN\Administrators".

I can only guess what is happening in your situation, it's either:

- You are a domain admin and don't realise it.
- Your environment has specified a custom group for this right and you are in that group.
- Something else I haven't thought of. ;-)

For reference, here's what TechNet has to say about "[Add workstations to domain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780195(WS.10).aspx)".

Comment: Whow, is that stil lvalid? That is pretty much the biggest stupid security risk I have ever seen.

Comment: It is still there in 2003. And I'd say that the bigger risk is tasking people who don't know AD really well with maintaining it.

Comment: Wait, hmm... does this mean that I can do the "add workstation" thing only 10 times, or that I can have only 10 workstations added at any moment, but if I remove some then I can add some more again?

Comment: Wait wait wait...has anyone tested it recently? Why is it that I get fifty UAC popups for trying to update my antivirus, but this is saying that I can add any rogue VM or laptop to a domain that I'm a member of (or has generic user accounts for groups of people)? Am I the only one that would think that this is a little against the least-privilege principal for rights assignment? Or is there a valid reason to have this as a default?

Comment: How does this create a security risk? A computer as-per-se doesn't have any more rights in the domain when it's added. It's the logged-on user that has rights in the domain. No?

Comment: @Vilx: I've heard it said with software testing that you can only prove that it has a bug, not that it doesn't have a bug. Because I don't know of a direct risk doesn't mean that it doesn't present a risk...there are plenty of users that are far more sneaky than are given credit.

Comment: @Vilx: although this does have some ramifications for things like inventory control, and on our domain systems can't web browse without separate browsing authentication unless the machine is on the domain, in which case it's running an authentication module from policy intallation. Or a user brings in an infected system from home and adds it to the domain, allowing network shares to get infected if their user on the business has access to the shares, etc.

Comment: True, but with this ideology you should stop using computers at all. Where does all the securing end and trust start?

Comment: The infected computers is an argument though, I suppose...

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim: While I'm inclined to agree with you regarding least privilege and unknown security risks, I would say that joining a computer to a domain doesn't proffer any rights to the person logging on to the domain from the joined computer. As far as malware is concerned, a domain joined computer doesn't pose any more risk to a network than a workgroup computer does. If it did we'd all be running workgroups instead of domains as they'd be more secure from a malware perspective. But as we all know, computers in a workgroup can spread malware as easily as computers in a domain.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I think the idea was that on corporate machines you can enforce an antivirus and other things, but a home computer is a wildcard.

Comment: @Joeqwerty: If someone had an infected system from home lacking antivirus/spyware detection then joins it (maybe purposely?), then it does have greater potential for damage if your environment is controlled with approved software and antivirus on it. It's outside hardware that the admins don't have as much control over. I'm thinking that if shares on the domain have UserA's access privileges, it's easier to transparently infect things rather than having them log in manually via workgroup. I'm still not comfortable with this ability as a default being entirely safe.

Comment: @Vilx: Re: security end and trust start-There's a tradeoff, always has been. But it's silly to by *default* give users abilities that they don't reasonably need. That's part of the reason windows has had so many security issues...the initial versions made them basically administrators by default and conveyed those privileges. Now each version of windows is tightening security with default security settings and UAC privileges. This can easily become a debate of usability vs. security, but in the end I don't know why this privilege is allowed by default, so it probably shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a computer to a Windows domain, your ID needs a few permissions:

Create/modify computer objects /
Change password

and maybe one or two others.

Check your account and you'll probably find that, somewhere, these permissions (or more) are set.

Comment: Nope, all you need is the Add workstations to domain right, which is given to Authenticated Users by default, for up to 10 PC's